# How do I export an HTML file with a XLS extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xls

I'm trying to generate reports. I already created the HTML table in a view and wanted to follow the approach talked about in "[Exporting data to CSV and Excel in your Rails app](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/09/exporting-data-to-csv-and-excel-in-your-rails-app/)".

I read:

> "On my project I save the html table into a file, but give it the xls extension instead of html. e.g table.xls. I then send it to the browser with the Excel mime type, and Excel will open this file and will also format the table like the html table is, so you'll get boldened headings and cell background colors etc.. "
>
> "The easiest way I know is to generate an HTML file with a table and give it an XLS extension. The HTML charset is respected, you can have linebreaks as much as you want, little or big endian is not an issue, th-tags define the column-headers and there are already plenty of solutions to build the file."

How can I save the HTML table into a file, and give it an `.XLS` extension to open it in Excel?

Comment: Your "some users" are completley wrong. "Generate an HTML file with a table and give it an XLS extension" is completely meaningless/useless advice. The blog post you link to already has a pretty good explanation of how to generate a CSV that can be read by Excel. If there's something there you don't understand, ask.

Comment: @jrochkind well the post author, who is a respected programmer in the rails community, said "Niko and Chris told us that we can you can also work with HTML tables in Excel, which is simple as well and even allows formatting." so I don't think those solutions would be completely meaningless/useless advice

Comment: http://blog.brijeshshah.com/export-to-excel-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Is there a more official extension than .xls that means "HTML meant to be displayed in Excel"?

Comment: @leonel I'm still fighting with this idea, as someone though it would be "simple" to encapsulate an html as "xls", as excel already support this "workaround". The problem is, that most people don't think like that, and expect an "xls" to be what it should: Roo, asxlx, casxlx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if that's good advice or not. Personally I always stick to csv. But here's how you would do it.

```
class ExportController < ApplicationController
  def export
    html = build_html_table()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls { send_data html, :type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => 'export.xls' }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in config/initializers/mime_types.rb you'll need to append:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.ms-excel', :xls
```